# ANDROID: How do I know when a picture I took has finished writing to the file?

Tags: android, camera

Using the android camera API I take a picture using .takepicture() and in my Camera.PictureCallback function I call

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
fos.write(data);
fos.close();
```

this works great although I want to immediately check how many files are in the directory and pick a random picture to show.  After fos.close() I check and it does not show right away that the new picture is in the directory.  How can I wait for the right time to check the directory for number of files?  Thanks

Comment: use asynstask for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a AsyncTask for doing that.

Your writing is start inonPreExecute and writing is finished in onPostExecute.

```
class MyLodingAsycTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{




        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // start image writing
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // image write is completed
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            /// save your image
            return null;
        }

    }
```